# Theano tensor type keeps changing and won't let me pass data

Tags: python, matrix, vector, machine-learning, theano

I have a script that returns two arrays of data:

```
def bankcsv(file_name='banklist.csv', table='Closing Date'):

          with open(file_name, 'rb') as cf:
               df = pd.read_csv(cf)
               bcd = (df[table].values.tolist())

          n = []
          for i in bcd: n.append(i.split('-')[-1])
          ar = np.array(n)
          u,c = np.unique(ar, return_counts=True)
          bd = dict(zip(u,c))
          year     = []
          failures = []
          for key in sorted(bd):
              year.append([float(key)])
              failures.append(float(bd[key]))

          return year, failures

y, x  = bankcsv()
print y
print x
```

> [[0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0], [7.0], [8.0], [9.0], [10.0], [11.0], [12.0], [13.0], [14.0], [15.0], [16.0], [17.0]]
>
> [2.0, 4.0, 11.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 25.0, 140.0, 157.0, 92.0, 51.0, 24.0, 18.0, 8.0, 5.0, 3.0]

And I attempted to pass these values to a simple regression function in theano:

```
# Load training data.
train_x = np.asarray([[0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]])
train_y = np.asarray([1.0, 1.1, 3.0, 2.0, 5.0])

# Parameters.
learning_rate = 0.1
n_dims = 1
n_steps = 10

# Define model.
x = T.matrix(name='x')  # Input matrix with examples.
w = theano.shared(value=np.zeros((n_dims, 1),  # Parameters of the model.
        dtype=theano.config.floatX),
        name='w', borrow=True)
f = function([x], T.dot(w, x))  # Linear regression.
```

but no matter what I do, `train_y` keeps giving me an error

`TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, vector) (of Variable <TensorType(float32, vector)>) into Type TensorType(float32, matrix). You can try to manually convert <TensorType(float32, vector)> into a TensorType(float32, matrix).`

I can't convert it, and all my attempts to reshape, recast of flatten it have failed. Removing the brackets does nothing, the error simply switched.

`TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, matrix) (of Variable <TensorType(float32, matrix)>) into Type TensorType(float32, vector). You can try to manually convert <TensorType(float32, matrix)> into a TensorType(float32, vector).`

What do I need to do to fix this?

***EDIT:*** Here's my full code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "device=cpu,floatX=float32"
import theano
from theano import function
from theano import pp
from theano import tensor as T
from theano.printing import min_informative_str


def bankcsv(file_name='banklist.csv', table='Closing Date'):

          with open(file_name, 'rb') as cf:
               df = pd.read_csv(cf)
               bcd = (df[table].values.tolist())

          n = []
          for i in bcd: n.append(i.split('-')[-1])
          ar = np.array(n)
          u,c = np.unique(ar, return_counts=True)
          bd = dict(zip(u,c))
          year     = []
          failures = []
          for key in sorted(bd):
              year.append([float(key)])
              failures.append(float(bd[key]))

          return year, failures

yy, xx  = bankcsv()

x = np.asarray(xx, 'float32')
y = np.asarray(yy, 'float32')
print type(y)
print type(x)

#raise SystemExit

# Load training data.
train_x = np.asarray(x)
train_y = np.asarray(y)

# Parameters.
learning_rate = 0.1
n_dims = 1
n_steps = 10

# Define model.
x = T.matrix(name='x')  # Input matrix with examples.
w = theano.shared(value=np.zeros((n_dims, 1),  # Parameters of the model.
        dtype=theano.config.floatX),
        name='w', borrow=True)
f = function([x], T.dot(w, x))  # Linear regression.

# Define objective function.
y = T.vector(name='y')  # Output vector with y values.

# Define loss function.
loss = T.mean((T.dot(x, w).T - y) ** 2)

# Build the gradient descent algorithm.
g_loss = T.grad(loss, wrt=w)

train_model = function(inputs=[],
                       outputs=loss,
                       updates=[(w, w - learning_rate * g_loss)],
                       givens={
                           x: train_x,
                           y: train_y
                       })

# Execute the gradient descent algorithm.
for i in range(n_steps):
    print "cost", train_model()

# Plot results.
plt.figure()
plt.plot([a[0] for a in train_x], train_y, 'r')
plt.plot([a[0] for a in train_x], [f([xx])[0] for xx in train_x], 'b')
plt.set_xlim(0, 20)
plt.set_ylabel('Failed banks')
plt.set_xlabel('Years')
plt.grid()
plt.title('title')
plt.show()
```

Comment: the _incomplete_ example doesn't give the same errors. I ran this and since its a scalar times a vector, you could get away `T.dot(x, w)`

Comment: if this isn't what you want give us a better example that _actually_ reproduces the error

Comment: Hey, I just added my full code.